# Pandas: select rows if a specific column satisfies a certain condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, slice

Say I have this dataframe `df`:

```
    A   B   C
0   1   1   2
1   2   2   2
2   1   3   1
3   4   5   2
```

Say you want to select all rows which column `C` is `>1`. If I do this:

```
newdf=df['C']>1
```

I only obtain `True` or `False` in the resulting df. Instead, in the example given I want this result:

```
    A   B   C
0   1   1   2
1   2   2   2
3   4   5   2
```

What would you do? Do you suggest using `iloc`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I select rows from a DataFrame based on column values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17071871/how-do-i-select-rows-from-a-dataframe-based-on-column-values)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
newdf=df[df['C']>1]
```

Comment: this and piRSquared answers work perfectly. I like this one more, because easier to remember

Answer (score 5):

use [`query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html)

```
df.query('C > 1')
```

[image]